# How ensure that scala.js method parameter is a literal

Tags: scala.js

how can I ensure that a method receive a javascript literal (js.dynamic.literal). It is not a type but it is js.Dynamic so it can be anything.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

There is no way, the Scala.js type system is able to enforce that. It also seems a quite arbitrary restriction to me.

A couple of things come to mind:

### Literally what you are asking for:

Use a macro to enforce that the argument to your method is a (JS) literal. This is what you also have to do, if you want to check if its, for example, a String literal.

Note that not every call to `js.Dynamic.literal` produces a JS object literal at the end. Consider:

```
val mySeq = Seq("a" -> 1, "b" -> 2)
js.Dynamic.literal(mySeq: _*)
```

### What you might want to be doing:

If you are creating facade types for a library and are creating option objects, we recommend the following pattern:

```
def myMethod(opts: MyMethodOptions): Unit = js.native

trait MyMethodOptions extends js.Object {
  val debug: Boolean
  val fast: Boolean
}

object MyMethodOptions {
  def apply(debug: Boolean = false, fast: Boolean = false): MyMethodOptions = 
    js.Dynamic.literal(debug = debug, fast = fast).asInstanceOf[MyMethodOptions]
}
```

Invoke like this:

```
myMethod(MyMethodOptions(fast = true))
```

That way the cast to `MyMethodOptions` is contained in the companion, so the type unsafe part is minimal and contained.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer. I'm doing a facade for sigma.js library. What I want is insure in compilation time that an object that has at less a field, for example to add a node to the graph it have to has an "id" field or the function fail. How can I do that?

Comment: Just how I have shown in the second part of my answer: Make a facade option trait for it and use it.